# How can I detect the number of lit faces on a mesh?

Tags: webgl, three.js

I have a number of objects arranged in a `THREE.scene`, and I want to calculate or retrieve a relative value indicating how much light each object is receiving from a single `PointLight` source. Simplified example:

[image: block example]

With the light positioned at the camera, Block **1**'s value might be 0.50 since 3 of 6 faces are completely exposed, while **2** is ~0.33 and **3** is ~1.67.

I could probably do this the hard way by drawing a ray from the light toward the center of each face and looking at the intersects, but I'm assuming it's possible to directly retrieve the light level of each face.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This code takes the object's global matrix in consideration.

```js
var amount = 0;

var rotationMatrix = new THREE.Matrix4();
var vector = new THREE.Vector3();
var centroid = new THREE.Vector3();
var normal = new THREE.Vector3();

for ( var i = 0; i < objects.length; i ++ ) {

    var object = objects[ i ];

    rotationMatrix.extractRotation( object.matrixWorld );

    for ( var j = 0; j < object.geometry.faces.length; j ++ ) {

        var face = object.geometry.faces[ j ];

        centroid.copy( face.centroid );
        object.matrixWorld.multiplyVector3( centroid );

        normal.copy( face.normal );
        rotationMatrix.multiplyVector3( normal );

        vector.sub( light.position, centroid ).normalize();

        if ( normal.dot( vector ) > 0 ) amount ++;

    }

}
```

Comment: This looks like it will set `amount` to the sum of lit faces for *all* objects (please correct me if I'm wrong), but the information here is still extremely helpful, and the `normal` test does answer the title question nicely.  See my answer for what I'm using to count only exposed faces.

Comment: Yes, this sums all objects. Seems like I got slightly confused on what the requirements were. Good to see that you managed to get the right code out of this one though.

Answer (score 4):

I think something like this should do the trick.

```js
var amount = 0;
var faces = mesh.geometry.faces;
for ( var i = 0; i < geometry.faces.length; i ++ ) {

    if ( geometry.faces[ i ].normal.dot( light.position ) > 0 ) amount ++;

}
```

Comment: This works well for a single object, but it will return the same value for all three cubes in my example.  I need to exclude faces from the count that are (mostly) blocked from the light by other objects.  Would it make sense to point a `Ray` from the light toward each face centroid, and test that the first intersected object === `mesh`?

Answer (score 1):

(Warning: Brute force method!)

I'm including this for reference since it's what I'm currently using to meet all of the requirements described in the question.  This function considers a face unlit if its center is not directly visible from the light's position.

I have no rotation matrix to consider for my application.

```js
function getLightLevel(obj) {
    /* Return percentage of obj.geometry faces exposed to light */
    var litCount = 0;

    var faces = obj.geometry.faces;
    var faceCount = faces.length; 
    var direction = new THREE.Vector3();
    var centroid = new THREE.Vector3();

    for (var i=0; i < faceCount; i++) {
        // Test only light-facing faces (from mrdoob's first answer).
        if (faces[i].normal.dot(light.position) > 0) {
            centroid.add(obj.position, faces[i].centroid);
            direction.sub(centroid, light.position).normalize();

            // Exclude face if centroid is obscured by another object.
            var ray = new THREE.Ray(light.position, direction);
            var intersects = ray.intersectObjects(objects);

            if (intersects.length > 0 && intersects[0].face === faces[i]) {
                litCount ++;
            }
        }
    }
    return litCount / faceCount;
}
```

Comment: This is not good... Try to work around my suggested code. With this code you're doing ^2 checks (for every face you're testing all the faces again with Ray).

Comment: @mrdoob This is a one-time check on a small number of objects, but I'm still looking for a better way to handle it.  It's important for me to know which faces are blocked from the light by others, and I was hoping there might be a way to access some values directly from the lighting system when shadows are enabled.